# How to convert a java.util.stream.Stream into an array?

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

What would `streamToArray` need to do in the following code?

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, 3);
int[] array = streamToArray(stream); // array = [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IntStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) has the member method [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--), that does exactly what you need:

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, 3);
int[] array = stream.toArray();
```

Comment: Hidden in plain sight! :)